# Trouble writing a command that outputs three different commands to a file

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have to write a single command that runs the date, ls, and pwd utilities at the same time and redirects their output to a text file. I can't seem to figure this one out, a single command is fine but three is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute the commands in a `subshell` then redirect to your out file.

```
 (date; ls; pwd) > /path/to/file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or in the current shell, use `{ date; ls; pwd; } > file`

Comment: Your welcome. If this worked for you please be sure to accept it as your answer. Thanks.